# Rails 4 - What is the difference between request.original_fullpath and request.fullpath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, uri, query-string

I need to store user search queries in our db for tracking search history. I know that **request.original_url** will give me the query string as an absolute url.

```
http://www.example.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keywords=cars&view=grid
```

I would prefer storing the relative url path. With that said, for a relative url with all params what is the difference between **request.original_fullpath** and **request.fullpath**? They seem to be the same thing?

**request.original_fullpath**

```
/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keywords=cars&view=grid
```

**request.fullpath**

```
/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keywords=cars&view=grid
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[original_fullpath](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/original_fullpath) returns a String with the last requested path including their params.

[fullpath](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/fullpath) returns the String full path including params of the last URL requested.

The difference between `original_fullpath` and `fullpath` is that, `original_fullpath` method doesn’t include parameters that weren’t in the original url (i.e. parameters that were sent via POST instead of GET).

Comment: I appreciate the response. Its still a bit confusing to me. For my case, It sounds like I would want to use fullpath since our search is using GET request method and at times some requests are being done via ajax. I want to make sure I am always capturing the full request url.

Comment: @Bryan, Exactly, `original_fullpath` wont include the POST method params, so if you always wants to capture the params, using `fullpath` is the way to go. Let me know if you have any other question.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to add [original_fullpath](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/original_fullpath) ignores redirects, while [fullpath](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/fullpath) includes them, for example:

```
# some_spec.rb
describe 'collections' do
  before do
    get '/collections'
  end
  context 'user is not signed in' do
    it 'should redirect to /unauthenticated' do
      expect(request.original_fullpath).to eq '/collections'
      expect(request.fullpath).to eq '/unauthenticated'
    end
  end
end
```